# Windows API, Automate keypress VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm trying to automate a "ctrl+c" keypress using the windows API in vb.net. I've tried using the SendKey() command but that isn't working. Apparently it targets the active window which for some reason isn't working in this case. So i'm looking for a windows API alternative. This is what I have so far:

```
 Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer

 Sub example()
        SendMessage(&HFFFF, 256, &H43, 0) ' Keydown
        '   SendMessage(0, 257, &H43, 65539) ' Keyup
 End Sub
```

It is supposed to automate a simple key press for "C", but its not working. Any help would be most appreciated

Additional Notes: What I'm trying to do is to just automate a "ctrl +c". I am trying to copy content from inside a game.

When the "ctrl+C" is being invoked, the window is active and on top of all other windows and the required text is selected. When I manually press "ctrl+c" in this case, it copies the required text but when I use sendkey(^{C}) nothing happens. So I'm looking for an API alternative.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? Where do you want to copy text from?

Comment: What is the `&HFFFF` HWND value supposed to represent? Where are you trying to copy text from? "isn't working in this case" isn't useful unless you explain what "in this case" means. `SendMessage` is most likely not the way you should be going here, but without a clear explanation of what you're trying to do, it's difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: I've added more info to the question, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'SendMessage' API call uses Window Messages to dispatch the events which are generated by a key press. If you are targeting a "Console Window", this will not work. Further, games which rely on GetKeyboardState and/or DINPUT will mostly likely not respect control state sent via SendKeys/SendMessage.

You would probably want something more along the lines of `SendInput` to simulate a hardware event, rather than dispatch a generic Window Message, which will work in your particular case.

There are also event routing (and rejection) rules based on:

1. Is the target a foreground window?
2. Does the target have focus, and is it active?

And for mouse events:

3. Is the target and target area occluded by another window?

Additionally, since you are targeting a game:

4. Some games rely on `GetKeyboardState` and similar API calls, thus they do not respect Window Messages which specify control/alt/shift key states. Again, you will probably want to use an API which simulates hardware events (such as `SendInput`), and in this case you may also want to use [SetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the state of Control/Alt/Shift keys (among others.)

You may be able to lift some code/ideas from [Mubox](https://github.com/wilson0x4d/Mubox/blob/6fd6bcc1f31984a42baf298deab196fe4b0dfc11/Mubox/Control/Input/InputQueue.cs#L343) which is able to do exactly what you're attempting.

Hope that helps.

References:

- [MSDN Documentation : SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN Documentation : SetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [PInvoke.NET : SetKeyboardState](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetKeyboardState.html)
- [PInvoke.NET : SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html)

Comment: 1&2: Yes and Yes, 3- Mouse events are working fine. I've added some more info in the question hope that helps

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how this could be done?

Comment: When doing p/invoke work you may consider checking http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetKeyboardState.html as they generally have user submitted examples in addition to the pinvoke declarations you will need. I am a C# programmer and while I can help with the details, concepts and technology here I cannot provide a "quality" VB.NET example that would be any more useful than what you would find on pinvoke.net (which is way too much to cross-paste to SO, IMO.)

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for but thanks for the references:)